# Php mysqli extension and timestamp index

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a problem with php mysqli extension and timestamp index.

I've got a Mysql table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `user_id` int(10)  unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created` timestamp  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'accepted',    
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     KEY `created` (`created`),    
     KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`oid`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I make request like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE created='2013-09-24 19:35:09';
```

When I use EXPLAIN of this request from Mysql console or from php Mysql extension I see:

```
possible_keys: created    
key: created    
key_len: const  
ref: const    
rows: 2
```

But when I make the same EXPLAIN request from php Mysqli extension I've got result:

```
possible_keys: null    
key: null       
key_len: null      
ref: null     
rows: 31597251
```

That's mean, that mysqli extension doesn't see datetime index and can't use it. USE INDEX (created) and FORCE INDEX (created) doesn't help.

How can I 'explain' to Mysqli extension that datetime index should be used?

Comment: Please, provide your PHP code which results in your FULL SCAN case.

Comment: not clear enough...provide code samples

Comment: That's just impossible. Mysqli has nothing to do with query plans. Mysqli don't execute your queries - it's just an API to send your query to mysql server.

Answer (score -1):

I have found solution.

I should use:

```
SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE created>=TIMESTAMP("2013-09-24 19:35:09");
```

And than index is always used. In another case mysql tries to compare int (datetime) with string and can't.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: But `>=` is not the same as `=`. You're surely mistaken somewhere. Also, doing `TIMESTAMP()` on datetime value makes no sense. The explanation you have got is a false one. The problem is somewhere else. Most likely you were running your mysqli query against wrong database.

Comment: Or may be you were indeed using `=` for the `const` query while `>=` made it full scan. When engine decides that more than 50% of records involved, no index is used.

Comment: >"doing TIMESTAMP() on datetime value makes no sense"
oh, really?)) Did You try it? I think, it's  no sense to answer, if you are not in the subject)

Comment: Yes, I did. The latter sentence belongs to your own answer, I presume. That's quite true.